# Fovis: fatal error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, dependencies, fovis, library, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have downloaded the visual odometry package Fovis (which is not a ros package) and I am trying to compile it using rosbuild on Fuerte and ubuntu 12.04. When I `$rosmake ros_fovis` which is the ROS package I created, I get the following error:

`In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:34:0, from /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/ros_fovis/libfovis/frame.cpp:1: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic/include/linux/stddef.h:4:28: fatal error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

I tried adding this line to the CMakeList.txt : `include_directories(/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic/include/linux)` but I still get the same error.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a specific library I need to add?

Thanks for your help,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54148/fovis:-fatal-error:-linux/compiler.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Khalid,

I cannot answer your question but want to point you to our wrapper for fovis: [fovis_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fovis_ros).
Feel free to use it under GPL license and look around in the implementation.
Any feedback is appreciated!

Stephan

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-14**:
Hi Stephan, thanks for your reply, does the fovis_ros wrapper support kinect yet?

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-02-14**:
Yes, since yesterday ;)

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-15**:
sweet. ill give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made the non-ROS-package version of Fovis as a ROS package that works with kinect. I show you what I have done:

-Create a ROS package (I also made the package to be an eclipse project). Inside the package, add 2 directories: /fovis and /src.

-Download the fovis library wherever you want.

-Copy the files from fovis source in /fovis/libfovis/libfovis (excluded the cmakelist inside), place them into /your_package/fovis

-Actually, there is a Kinect example in fovis source, which is in /fovis/libfovis/examples/fv-example-openni. Copy main.cpp, data_capture.cpp and depth_image.cpp into /your_package/src .

-Add these lines into cmakelist file in the package.

```
include_directories(/usr/include/openni)

rosbuild_add_executable(ros_frame src/ros_frame.cpp src/data_capture.cpp fovis/depth_image.cpp fovis/fast.cpp fovis/feature_matcher.cpp fovis/frame.cpp fovis/gauss_pyramid.c fovis/grid_filter.cpp fovis/initial_homography_estimation.cpp fovis/intensity_descriptor.cpp fovis/internal_utils.cpp fovis/motion_estimation.cpp fovis/normalize_image.cpp fovis/primesense_depth.cpp fovis/pyramid_level.cpp fovis/rectification.cpp fovis/refine_feature_match.cpp fovis/refine_motion_estimate.cpp fovis/stereo_depth.cpp fovis/stereo_frame.cpp fovis/stereo_rectify.cpp fovis/tictoc.cpp fovis/visual_odometry.cpp  )

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(ros_frame OpenNI)
```

-Add these lines into manifest.xml in the package.

```
<rosdep name="eigen" />
<rosdep name="openni-dev" />
<rosdep name="ps-engine" />
```

-Use "rosdep install your_package" command to install the needed libraries.

-Connect the kinect and run the package in eclispe.

I dont know if there are some easier ways, but it works for me.

---

Originally posted by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) with karma: 13 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-02-14**:
The fovis source I downloaded is from https://code.google.com/p/fovis/ with this command "
git clone [https://code.google.com/p/fovis/"](https://code.google.com/p/fovis/%22)